# Help with limiting rotation of an armature

Tags: armature, pose-mode

I am totally new to animation and armatures in blender, and I have been following a tutorial to make an animated lamp. I have been trying to set a limit for the rotation of one of the bones of the armature, but it doesn't seem to be working. I set the limits on the local Y axis to -60 - 60, the piece rotates smoothly as expected:

[image] [image]

But, if I change the rotation limits to -90 - 90 (which is how I want it to be) the rotation is strange. It seems to only rotate some of the way and then it snaps to the limit points. I have no idea what is causing this, as the set up is exactly the same as it was before, just with a different limit.

[image] 
[image]

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Just a note to add : generally, don't use limits. Give the animators leeway and let them use their common sense

Answer (score 0):

I replicated exactly your setup and noticed that you have the "For Transform" box un-checked, That will help to maintain the values in transformations relative to the ones in the constrain modifier. 2 more things that will make it feel better is to set the "transform Orientation" to local, which I think you do, and use the 3D Gizmo.

Hope that helps.

[image]